# Can I add custom metrics and dimensions to to web plus app property

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web property that I could add custom metrics and dimensions to track them on my web app through: Admin --> Property Settings --> custom Definitions

But I created a new web + app property in my google analytics and I can't seem to find a way to add custom metrics and dimensions.

My question is: is it there a way to add custom metrics and dimensions to web + app properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer hit-, session-, and user-scoped custom definitions but in Google Analytics V2 you can use **user properties** and **custom event parameters**.